# I am struggling with the model below

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have this model
namespace AppCore.Entities;

```
public class ProductQuestion : _BaseEntity
{
    public ulong AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser? AppUser { get; set; }
    public ulong? AdminUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser? AdminUser { get; set; }
    public required string Question { get; set; }
    public string? Answer { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a new migration I get this error:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'AppUser.ProductQuestions' of type 'List<ProductQuestion>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Answer (score 0):

OnModelCreating you can try :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ProductQuestions)
    .WithOne(pq => pq.AppUser)
    .HasForeignKey(pq => pq.AppUserId);
```

Make sure your entity classes (e.g., 'AppUser' and 'ProductQuestion') have the necessary navigation properties and foreign key properties to support the relationship.

Comment: Each product question contains two user and one user ask question and the other the admin answer question basically one product question have two user